# EF 6 seamless connection with both Ms SQL and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have ASP.NET MVC application with default MS SQL 2012 data source. I need to make same app to work with MySQL db without much code change or separate compilation since both database are exact replica. I have browsed and notice following solutions :

1. Create separate SSDL using edmgen tool. - couldn't complete implementation example
2. Create separate EDMX - but how can I just switch between MsSQL and MySQL in web.config file
3. Applying *[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]* in DAL module - but this require separate compilation.

I referred following in my project :

- MySQL.Data
- MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6

And following is the settings in my web.config file :

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=xxxxx;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=pscope4" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="DefaultConnection-SQL" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=PScope4;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=xxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="PScopeDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DbModel.csdl|res://*/DbModel.ssdl|res://*/DbModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=xxxxx;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=pscope4&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="PScopeDB-SQL" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DbModel.csdl|res://*/DbModel.ssdl|res://*/DbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLSERVER2012;initial catalog=PScope4;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

```
  <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

I'm using Asp.Net.Identity, and its working fine with both MsSQL and MySQL. But am getting following error in my EF :

**Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.**

Comment: hmm...i added following code in my App_Startup in Global.asax and both working seamlessly :


    'ConnectionStringSettings cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"];
            if ( cs.ProviderName == "MySql.Data.MySqlClient")
            {
                  System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration());
            }'

But I will do thorough test to make sure all entities are working. Meanwhile I would wait others to comment on reliable method.